# Get button ID not entire button

Tags: android, android-studio

```
ArrayList<View> allButtons;
String button;
button = ((RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_main)).getTouchables().toString();

System.out.println(button);
```

Outputs:

> System.out: [android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton{7107785 VFED..C.. ........ 32,74-176,210 #7f0b0056 app:id/imageButton2}, android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton{c4b99da VFED..C.. ...P.... 66,256-242,352 #7f0b0057 app:id/button}]

How can i get just the id which is `button`

Comment: use `button.getId();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should write your code a s

```
ArrayList<View> allTouchables = ((RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_main)).getTouchables();
for (View view : allTouchables) {
    System.out.println(view.getId());
}
```

As above code returns all touchable views present into given container, you should also check about the type of view like

```
ArrayList<View> allTouchables = ((RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_main)).getTouchables();
for (View touchable : allTouchables) {
   // To check if touchable view is button or not
    if( touchable instanceof Button) {
        System.out.println(touchable.getId());
    }
}
```

---

To get string representation of id, you can write

```
String idString = view.getResources().getResourceEntryName(view.getId());
```

Comment: `System.out: 2131427414
System.out: 2131427415` this is what i am getting can i use this to look for the said element again? i mean i want to use this id to find the said element again

Comment: I want the first one get all touchables no need about the type only the string representation will do. will it and be back

Answer (score 2):

aah you can check the type of the views before adding to the arraylist.

```
ArrayList<Button>buttons = new ArrayList<>();
parentLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(parentID);

for(int i=0; i<parentLayout.getChildCount(); i++){
    View view = parentLayout.getChildAt(i);

   if(view instanceof Button){
       buttons.add((Button)view);
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So your want to check which button is clicked in the layout and process accordingly.

This you can achieve by two way.

**1. With getId()**

**xml**

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Next Layout"
    android:id="@+id/Next"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

**YourActivity**

```
  final Button nxtbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Next);



    nxtbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            int ID = nxtbtn.getId();

            if(ID == R.id.Next) // your R file will have all your id's in the literal form.
            {
                Log.e(TAG,""+ID);
            }
        }
    });
```

**2. With TAG**

**xml**

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Next Layout"
    android:tag="buttonA"
    android:id="@+id/Next"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

Just add a TAG attribute in your xml

**Your Activity**

```
  final Button nxtbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Next);



    nxtbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

           String Tag = nxtbtn.getTag().toString();
            Log.e("TAG", "" + Tag);
          if (Tag.equal("ButtonA")){ /* Your code here */}
        }
    });
```

Hope this might help.